# Draw image with zendPDF

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf

Im using the PDF parser that comes with zend framework. Im trying to trying draw an image, but get an error.

```
function addReklam($reklamblad)  //picture.png
{

    // kolla hur många sidor som skapats och lägg till en sista reklamsida:
    //Öppna fil här, lägg till den i PDF
    $fish = 0;
    if($this->drawed_lines<52)
    {
        $this->active_page = $this->pdf->pages[2];
        $fish = 1;
    }
    elseif($this->drawed_lines<92)
    {
        $this->active_page = $this->pdf->pages[3];
        $fish = 2;
    }
    elseif($this->drawed_lines<132)
    {
        $this->active_page = $this->pdf->pages[4];
        $fish = 3;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->active_page = $this->pdf->pages[5];
        $fish = 4;
    }


    //$this->active_page = $this->pdf->pages[5];        // sida 5 är reklamsidan
    $image = $this->imageWidthPath($reklamblad);
    $this->active_page->drawImage($image, $left, $bottom, $right, $top);
}
```

I get this message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method fakturapdf::imageWidthPath() in /data/web/script/pdffaktura/testpdf-txt.php on line 681
```

EDIT:
I've tried like this now:

```
function addReklam($reklamblad)
    {

        // kolla hur många sidor som skapats och lägg till en sista reklamsida:
        //Öppna fil här, lägg till den i PDF
        $fish = 0;
        if($this->drawed_lines<52)
        {
            $this->active_page = $this->pdf->pages[2];
            $fish = 1;
        }
        elseif($this->drawed_lines<92)
        {
            $this->active_page = $this->pdf->pages[3];
            $fish = 2;
        }
        elseif($this->drawed_lines<132)
        {
            $this->active_page = $this->pdf->pages[4];
            $fish = 3;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->active_page = $this->pdf->pages[5];
            $fish = 4;
        }


        //$this->active_page = $this->pdf->pages[5];        // sida 5 är reklamsidan
        $image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($reklamblad);
        $this->active_page->drawImage($image, 400, 400, 400, 400);


    }
```

This seems to work fine, I'll get no errors. But is this the correct way to use it? Nothing is printed to the PDF.

Comment: Where have you defined `imageWidthPath()`? It's not a Zend function nor a php function. Have you define it in the same class that the class where is addReklam() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's correct. It's `Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath` and not `$this->imageWidthPath()`.
It's a static method.

If it helps you, I found [it](http://devzone.zend.com/1064/zend_pdf-tutorial/).